# Automate Visual Studio 2017 Find and Replace

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2017

For a project refactoring, I need to execute 4 (regex) search and replace for, like, 80+ classes. Since the regex are very long, I'm currently copying and pasteing them from a txt note file... Ditto (a clipboard manager) helps me to speed up a little, but a better automation would be appreciated..! I tried with a couple of macro plug-ins but they don't work very well or are too much complicated (using envDTE). Anyone of you have ever needed to accomplish a similar task and found a solution to suggest?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: If you're sure the regex find/replace works as intended, you could write a quick console application to crawl your project folder for source files and then execute the regular expressions on them.

Comment: Agree with @JonathonChase. I think VS is holding you back. Just hack an app together (or something in linqpad) to do this for you.

Comment: Wow you&#39;ve been fast :) maybe I need to be more specific about a detail. In the project I need to find A replace with B, then copy B in another file and then find B and replace with C! Automating this is difficult because the second file (a new class) has to be created from scratch.. Thanks

Comment: If you already have a template or a quick sketch, that won't be a blocker. You may have add the precision to your question though, we're quite far of an MCVE.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try my [Visual Commander](https://vlasovstudio.com/visual-commander/) extension to automate this task. For example, to execute a search and replace with regex use the following code:

```
public void Run(EnvDTE80.DTE2 DTE, Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.Package package) 
{
    int options = (int)(EnvDTE.vsFindOptions.vsFindOptionsRegularExpression |
           EnvDTE.vsFindOptions.vsFindOptionsMatchCase |
           EnvDTE.vsFindOptions.vsFindOptionsMatchInHiddenText |
           EnvDTE.vsFindOptions.vsFindOptionsSearchSubfolders |
           EnvDTE.vsFindOptions.vsFindOptionsKeepModifiedDocumentsOpen);
    DTE.Find.FindReplace(EnvDTE.vsFindAction.vsFindActionReplaceAll,
        @"(\.Register\w*)\(""([^""]+)""",
        options,
        @"$1(nameof($2)",
        EnvDTE.vsFindTarget.vsFindTargetCurrentDocument);
}
```

See [DTE.Find.FindReplace](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/envdte.find.findreplace) documentation for more details.

Comment: That is exactly what I was looking for! Works like a charm, thank you!